# Spring message in form tag doesn't appear correctly

Tags: spring, jsp, character-encoding, internationalization

I'm trying to insert a spring:message tag into a `form`:... `tag`, here is the code :

```
<spring:message code="section.Wiki.titleofthearticle" var="intitule"/>
<form:input type="text" placeholder="Introduction " title="${intitule}"
 path="wikiArticleTitle" required="true"/>
```

and my message properties values is like this :`section.Wiki.titleofthearticle=**Intitule de l'article**`

but unfortunately my title attribute displayed like this : **`Intitule de l&#39;article`**

Is there a way to displayed correctly ?

Comment: You can try url encoding for special character.

Comment: when i put my var ${intitule} in a attribute rather than " title" attribute it works like a charm , so i don't think that it's a problem of encoding

Comment: The same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797756/i18n-charset-encoding-spring-jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change :

`<spring:message code="section.Wiki.titleofthearticle" var="intitule"/>`

To :

`<spring:message htmlEscape="false" code="section.Wiki.titleofthearticle" var="intitule"/>`

[Spring:message docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/taglib/tag/MessageTag.html)

Comment: hanya khoya beginmoh :)

Answer (score 1):

use encoding of message once (there are predefined methods in URLEncoder)

```
URLEncoder.encode(String s, String esc);
```

first parameter is String to be translated and second one is character encoding which you want.

Comment: How can this solve the issue ? assuming that all the work must be done inside the JSP file ?

Comment: you can write this java code in scriptlets and check (import ULDEncoder). you can also do the same in JS also (there are inbuilt function for encoding)