# I18N charset Encoding Spring-JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, character-encoding, internationalization, jstl

I'm trying to show `é` as a title of my `form:input` field, and I can't get it working.

### Example 1 :

```
<form:input type="text" path="something" title="é"/>
```

### Output :

[image]

### Example 2 :

```
<input type="text" title="<spring:message code="mySpecialChar" />"/>
```

### Output :

[image]

### Example 3 :

```
<form:input type="text" path="something" title="<spring:message code="mySpecialChar" />"/>
```

### Output :

**Error**, I'm not allowed to do that, to solve this, I've tried Example 4.

### Example 4 :

```
<spring:message code=mySpecialChar" var="mySpecialChar"/>
<form:input type="text" path="something" title="${mySpecialChar}"/>
```

### Output :

[image: Example 4]

How can I get my Example 4 working properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick search, I've found that I have to add `htmlEscape="false"` to my `<spring:message>` tag.

[**Spring:message docs**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/taglib/tag/MessageTag.html)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to unescape your value in a Controller, first thing you would have to autowire your *MessageSource*

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

than you can unescape using e.g. [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html)

```
 String message = messageSource.getMessage("mySpecialChar", null, Locale.getDefault());
 model.addAttribute("mySpecialChar", StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml([YOUR VALUE]));
```

than just

```
<form:input type="text" path="something" title="${mySpecialChar}"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sending any value from the controller, I'm using Spring I18N; and all the message are stored in a properties file, it means that I can't do such thing to solve this issue.

Comment: yes, so I've understood, I've added a part of how you grab a value from the properties file inside a controller. For what concerns your answer, if it works, great, that's that than. But I'm suprised, since the whole trouble is that you're using the value inside the title, and htmlEscape will escape it and store in the output stream (so basically display correctly), but it won't change the actual variable, so in your title, you will still see the html entity. Its what I'm expecting though I might be wrong

Comment: np, I'm glad if it was helpful in any way